# Jupyter %%prun magic output not displayed properly in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, ipython, ipython-magic

Since very recently I have a problem where the output of `%%prun` is not displayed properly in VS Code Jupyter (all output is on one line instead of in a nicely formatted table).

I tried reloading the window and restarting Jupyter but the problem still appears.

What could be causing the problem?

[image: Bug illustration]

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I'm using at the moment is saving the %prun output to a separate file and inspecting that file.

```
%prun -T tmp.txt my_fn()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that got fixed: [The output is not displayed in tabular form by using %%prun #11443](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/11443). The fix's milestone was January 2023, which has since been released, and I just tested that it works.